# Bootstrap datatables does not work correctly with thymeleaf th:block

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, jquery-plugins, thymeleaf

I am getting `nTd is undefined` when using `TableData` of `bootstrap`. I have already read in many forums that it's because of not having the same number of `td`'s and `th`'s in the header and body elements.
But I think it should work. I have counted the number of `td`s and `th`s and they are the same.
Here is my code:

```
<table id="searchResultTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <th:block th:each="element, iterStat  : ${searchResult}">

                    <tr>
                        
                        <td class="underline font-weight-bold" colspan="3"
                            data-toggle="collapse" th:data-target="|.demo${iterStat.count}|"
                            th:text="${element.key}" />
                            <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr th:id="'demo'+ ${iterStat.index}"
                        th:class="|accordian-body collapse demo${iterStat.count}|"
                        th:each="anews : ${element.value}">

                        

                        <td class="boldanditalic" th:text="${anews.getDate()}">Date</td>

                        <td class="boldanditalic" th:text="${anews.user.getFullname()}">
                            writer</td>

                        <td th:if="${!#strings.equals(anews.fp,'')}"
                            th:text="'$'+${anews.fp}">fp</td>
                        <td th:if="${!#strings.equals(anews.sep,'')}"
                            th:text="'$'+${anews.sep}">sep</td>
                        <td th:if="${!#strings.equals(anews.tp,'')}"
                            th:text="'$'+${anews.tp}">tp</td>
                        <td th:if="${!#strings.equals(anews.fop,'')}"
                            th:text="'$'+${anews.fop}">fop</td>
                        <td th:if="${!#strings.equals(anews.fp,'')}"
                            th:text="'$'+${anews.fp}">SP</td>
                        <td th:if="${!#strings.equals(anews.sip,'')}"
                            th:text="'$'+${anews.sip}">SP</td>
                        <td th:if="${!#strings.equals(anews.sp,'')}"
                            th:text="'$'+${anews.sp}">SP</td>

                    </tr>
                </th:block>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I even tried to add the `<th>` block in the header. But it didn't work.
I would appreciate your help.

Update:
I have added the following code in the header section:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#searchResultTable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Here you can find the links and scripts in the header:

```
<script
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"></script>

<link
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">


<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
    rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can find the screenshot of the result here: [image: Screenshot]

Update 2: If I remove the `th:block` section and add some simple elements, it works.

Comment: Can you show an example of the final HTML output and indicate if you're properly including DataTable as it is a 3rd party plugin.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your quick repy. I updated my question.

Comment: Double-check that your table structure is correct. It looks like you're using a `<th>` outside the `<tr>` of the table body. That might be causing the column count to result in an error.  COLUMN Count has to be the same, not row count.  So if you have 4 headers (ex: Name, Age, DOB, Email) DataTables expects each row of data to come with 4 columns.

Comment: @Thanks a lot. You're right. If I remove the th:block section and add some simple elements, it works. But do you know how to solve it preserving the th:block?
If I add a <tr> around the <th:block> I get another error regarding knowing the element.key.

Comment: Like `<td>` the `<th>` tag needs to be wrapped within a `<tr>...</tr>` to render properly. If you're having issues with the `:block` aspects you're describing it is probably more related to whatever the final output of your HTML is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `<thead>` row you have 9 cells, let's assume this is what you want;

Inside `<tbody>` you have 2 rows:

- The first row has 9 cells, but the first cell has `colspan=3`, which will give you 11 cells in total according to your `<thead>` row. This should be fixed in either remove 2 empty cells or remove `colspan`.
- The second row has 9 cells, but the last 7 cells are conditional and you may not have them at all or have some of them. To maintain the proper structure of the table you should remove the condition from cells and always have them.

Basically your code may look like ... (I might miss something as I didn't try this code, but you'll get an idea)

```
    <table id="searchResultTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <th:block th:each="element, iterStat  : ${searchResult}">

                <tr>
                    
                    <td class="underline font-weight-bold" colspan="3"
                        data-toggle="collapse" th:data-target="|.demo${iterStat.count}|"
                        th:text="${element.key}"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr th:id="'demo'+ ${iterStat.index}"
                    th:class="|accordian-body collapse demo${iterStat.count}|"
                    th:each="anews : ${element.value}">                      

                    <td class="boldanditalic" th:text="${anews.getDate()}">Date</td>

                    <td class="boldanditalic" th:text="${anews.user.getFullname()}">
                        writer</td>

                    <td th:text="${!#strings.equals(anews.fp,'')}? ${'$'+ anews.fp} : ''">fp</td>
                    <td th:text="${!#strings.equals(anews.sep,'')}? ${'$'+ anews.sep} : ''">sep</td>
                    <td th:text="${!#strings.equals(anews.tp,'')}? ${'$'+ anews.tp} : ''">tp</td>
                    <td th:text="${!#strings.equals(anews.fop,'')}? ${'$'+ anews.fop} : ''">fop</td>
                    <td th:text="${!#strings.equals(anews.sp,'')}? ${'$'+ anews.sp} : ''">sp</td>
                    <td th:text="${!#strings.equals(anews.sip,'')}? ${'$'+ anews.sip} : ''">sip</td>
                    <td th:text="${!#strings.equals(anews.fp,'')}? ${'$'+ anews.fp} : ''">fp</td>


                </tr>
            </th:block>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your proposed logic worked :). Your code did not work directly. But I tried the following and it worked: 
<td th:if="${!#strings.equals(anews.s_p,'')}"
      th:text="'$'+${anews.s_p}">Something</td>
      <td th:unless="${!#strings.equals(anews.s_p,'')}"th:text="''">Something</td>

Comment: @user1419243 I expected the code may not run as I typed it directly in SO. But I glad you have your fix. `th:if` and `th:unless` is overkill and you should consider using [Conditional expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions). Best regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try :).